# Brute force algorithm stops looping

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the combinations of three numbers that add to 810 and multiply to 10760040. This is what I have so far;

```
x = 1
y = 1
z = 1

keepGoing = 1

while keepGoing == 1:
    if x+y+z == 810:
        if x*y*z == 10760040:
            print(x)
            print(y)
            print(z)
        else:
            keepGoing = 2
            z = 1
            print("no z")
        elif z == 810:
        keepGoing = 2
        print("no")
    else:
        z += 1




while keepGoing == 2:
    if x+y+z == 810:
        if x*y*z == 10760040:
            print(x)
            print(y)
            print(z)
        else:
            keepGoing = 3
            z = 1
            y = 1
            print("no y")

    elif y == 810:
        keepGoing = 3
    else:
        z += 1
        keepGoing = 1

while keepGoing == 3:
    if x+y+z == 810:
        if x*y*z == 10760040:
            print(x)
            print(y)
            print(z)
            print("Success")
        else:
            print("Failure")
    elif x == 810:
        print("none")
    else:
        x += 1
        keepGoing = 1
```

I know this code is reaaaally basic but I haven't done any Python in a long time and I'm trying to find a list of numbers that add to make 810 and multiply to 10760040, any help would be fantastic, thanks!

Comment: You have to nest those three loops inside each other. Right now, you are testing all values for `z`, using the initial values for `x` and `y`, then all values for `y`, using the initial for `x` and the final for `z`, and so on.

Comment: Sounds more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: So how would I nest the loops? At which point? @tobias_k

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner and simpler piece of code would be:

```
for x in range(1,810):
    for y in range(1,810-x):
        z = 810-x-y
        if x*y*z == 10760040:
            print 'x={},y={},z={}'.format(x,y,z)
```

Comment: Wasting cycles on negative values of `z`, values of `y` < `x` and the brief isn't clear whether re-use of numbers in the candidates is permitted.

Comment: @MattH: You're right, I added `-x` to the inner loop. As a side-note, there are probably a few more efficiency-wise improvements to make, since this is essentially a system of 2 equations in 3 variables that we need to solve. However, I concentrated mostly on simplifying OP's code, which seemed way over complicated for the specific problem at hand.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you can restrict the ranges to `for x in range(SUM // 3): for y in range(x, (SUM - x) // 2):`, assuming `x <= y <= z`.